# How to solve buildozer md5sum bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, packaging, python-packaging

I am trying to package my kivy app for android using buildozer.
I installed all the requirments and dependencies but I'm getting a weird error I don't know how to solve! here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 216, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 555, in build_recipes
    recipe.download_if_necessary()
  File "/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 347, in download_if_necessary
    self.download()
  File "/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 383, in download
    'for {} recipe').format(self.name))
ValueError: Generated md5sum does not match expected md5sum for sdl2 recipe
# Command failed: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=Tarot --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,random --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     TMPDIR = '/var/folders/g9/1qpkcg7j0p74t1kp_zfwnm2c0000gn/T/'
#     __CFBundleIdentifier = 'com.apple.Terminal'
#     XPC_FLAGS = '0x0'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.DYfET6UirI/Listeners'
#     XPC_SERVICE_NAME = '0'
#     TERM_PROGRAM = 'Apple_Terminal'
#     TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '440'
#     TERM_SESSION_ID = '0BB319D4-A23C-4FDE-9FD5-5EF7494690CF'
#     SHELL = '/bin/zsh'
#     HOME = '/Users/bfx0.9'
#     LOGNAME = 'bfx0.9'
#     USER = 'bfx0.9'
#     PATH = ('/Users/bfx0.9/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin '
 'Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin')
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PWD = '/Users/bfx0.9/PycharmProjects/Taroot-android'
#     OLDPWD = '/Users/bfx0.9'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/buildozer'
#     __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = '0x1F5:0x0:0x0'
#     __PYVENV_LAUNCHER__ = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/Users/bfx0.9/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/Users/bfx0.9/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/Users/bfx0.9/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

(This is not part of the question I just added this cause stack over flow wouldn't let me post my question cause the code was too long lol!!!!)

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .buildozer directory in your app directory then running again?

Comment: You could also try looking at the sdl2 download somewhere in the .buildozer folder, maybe it downloaded the wrong thing or the download was corrupted